Godot Enemy Follow AI
I need some help with my Code since I can't find any solution. I'm fairly new to programming especially with GDScript and I'm trying to implement an easy and basic Follow AI Enemy but I can't find any good Scripts because every other is in Godot 3. In Godot 3 we could use the move_and_slide with arguments likemove_and_slide(direction * speed) but now we can't and I can't find a solution, here my Code:
extends CharacterBody2D

const speed = 35
var dir: Vector2

var isBatChase: bool 

var player_position
var target_position

@onready var player = get_parent().get_node("CharacterBody2D")

func _physics_process(delta):
    player_position = player.position
    target_position = (player_position - position).normalized()

func _ready():
    isBatChase = true

func _process(delta):
    move(delta)
    handleAnimation()

func move(delta):
    if isBatChase == true:
        if position.distance_to(player_position) > 1:
            velocity = position.direction_to(player_position) * speed * delta
    if isBatChase == false:
        velocity += dir * speed * delta
    move_and_slide()

func _on_direction_timer_timeout():
    $DirectionTimer.wait_time = choose([1.0, 1.5, 2.0])
    if isBatChase == false:
        dir = choose([Vector2.RIGHT, Vector2.LEFT, Vector2.UP, Vector2.DOWN])

func handleAnimation():
    var animatedSprite = $AnimatedSprite2D
    animatedSprite.play("flying")
    if dir.x == 1:
        animatedSprite.flip_h = true
    elif dir.x == -1:
        animatedSprite.flip_h = false
    
func choose(array):
    array.shuffle()
    return array.front()

enter image description here
That is my Scene

Where is the issue arising? At a glance, it looks like it should work, albeit the enemy would move really slowly.

The enemy moves but he very slowly to the top and not to my direction

try player_position = player.global_position and target_position = (player_position - global_position).normalized(), maybe? EDIT: There's actually more position grabs you'd have to change, sorry

he still flies up but now in my direction. So basicly he flies in my direction and up.
Is there any other way to implement a follow ai.

I'd play around with which ones you use global_position for and which you don't. Calling global_position on the bat itself may be a bad idea.

Thank you for your help, i've figured out what the problem was. It was just that my character sprite was a bit far away from the x and y point from the character "Itself" in the scene. Basicly it was just an issue of my scene

Ah, that'll do it. Glad you found the issue!
